# Acrescentar item em um template do pie chart Telerik

Tags: javascript, telerik

Estou desenvolvendo um gráfico utilizando o Telerik. No gráfico preciso mostrar, no template, algumas informações relevantes, como a formação, percentual e total. Porém só consigo mostrar duas (formação e percentual), que no caso o Telerik vem por padrão, que é o **field** e o **categoryField**. Tem o **explodField** também, mas ele só serve para destacar a parte do gráfico que foi selecionada. 
Segue abaixo o código:

```
    function createChart(data) {
    $("#divGraficoFinanceiro").kendoChart({
        theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                background: "transparent",
                template: "Formação: #= category #: \n Percentual: #= value#% \n Total: #= total#"
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "pie",
            field: "percentage",
            categoryField: "source",
            explodeField: "explode"
            //adicionar o novo item => totalField: "total"

        }],
    });
```

Como poderia adicionar um novo item dentro do **series:** e mostrá-lo no template do **seriesDefault:** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, vejo que no template você já possui uma variável com o total, acredito ela esteja em javascript, então o único problema é em exibi-la.

O telerik já dispõe de formas padrões para isso, neste caso: `#= var_telerik #`, mas quando você quer exibir uma variável própria em javascript, use: `#: sua_var #`. Neste caso seu código ficaria:

```
template: "Formação : #= category# \n Percentual : ${value} % \n Total : #: total #"
```

Pode testar que vai funcionar!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado